# How do I highlight/un-highlight div if checkbox is clicked OR it's parent div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Right now when I click on `li`, it is highlighted correctly. However, when I click on the checkbox itself, **there is no response**. How do I highlight/un-highlight the `li` when clicking on either the `li` **or** the `checkbox` itself?

I also do not wish to adjust this part of my jQuery:   `$('.rightP').find('ul').on(` (because the elements inside the `ul` are **generated dynamically**) if possible.

---

**HTML**

```
<div class = "rightP">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="sender">
                <span>
                      <input type="checkbox">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id=2 class="message">
                 <p>test</p>
            </div>
            ...
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
```

**JQuery :**

```
deleteIDs = [];
$('.rightP').find('ul').on("click","li",function(event) {

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if(checkbox.hasClass('open')){
        if(!checkbox.prop("checked") ){
            checkbox.prop("checked",true);
            $(this).css({'background-color':"#EEEEEE"});
            $(this).find('div.message').each(function(){
                deleteIDs.push($(this).prop('id'));
            });
        } else {
            checkbox.prop("checked",false);
            $(this).css({'background-color':"white"});
            $(this).find('div.message').each(function(){
                var deleteID = $(this).prop('id');
                deleteIDs = $.grep(deleteIDs,function(value){
                    return (value!=deleteID);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want handle li click. You must not use check checkbox. You image and change it src to click.png when click and noclick.png when no click. Hope this help!

Ok if you dont want image i mention you my full code no use image, it work ok

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
<div class = "rightP">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="sender">
                <span>
                      <input type="checkbox">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id=2 class="message">
                 <p>test</p>
            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>

    <script>
     deleteIDs = [];
     var isnotcheck=true;
      var clickcheckbox=false;
    $('.rightP').find('ul').on("click","input",function(event) {
          clickcheckbox=true;
          isnotcheck=!isnotcheck;
        });
$('.rightP').find('ul').on("click","li",function(event) {
    ;
        if(!clickcheckbox)
        {
         isnotcheck=!isnotcheck;
        }
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        clickcheckbox=false;
        if(!isnotcheck ){
            checkbox.prop("checked",true);
            $(this).css({'background-color':"#EEEEEE"});
            $(this).find('div.message').each(function(){
             deleteIDs.push($(this).prop('id'));

            });
        } else {
            //alert(checkbox);
            checkbox.prop("checked",false);
            $(this).css({'background-color':"white"});
            $(this).find('div.message').each(function(){
                var deleteID = $(this).prop('id');

                deleteIDs = $.grep(deleteIDs,function(value){
                    return (value!=deleteID);
                });
            });

    }
});

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You look two event. li click and checkbox click , two event occured if you click on checkbox if no one event occured. You can see my variable

```
var isnotcheck=true;
var clickcheckbox=false;
```

to know click or not click checkbox.
 Hope this help!

Comment: Are you saying just to add this small functionality require me to use image? No, I can't see how it works that way. Actually, I already can handle `li` click. The only problem now is when I click the checkbox in the `li`, there is no response but if I click `li` element, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than this line

`$('.rightP').find('ul').on("click","li",function(event) {`

You can try

```
$('.rightP').on("click","ul li",function(event) {
```

Comment: No difference. Maybe you misunderstood my question. Actually, my jQuery code works but when I click the checkbox, there is no response. There is only response when I click the `li` containing the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with generated content you should use deferred event handlers, here's an example using Jquery UI to apply the highlight effect when you click either the checkbox or div.

http://jsbin.com/kibicega/1/

Comment: However, when I click on the div in your example, the checkbox isn't checked. Also, I would like to refrain from using jQuery UI. Thanks.